# Which will give faster SN2 reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, nucleophilicity

> In $\ce{H2C=CH-Br}$ and $\ce{H3C-CH2-Br}$, which will react faster towards a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction?

According to me, as double bond exhibit −*I* effect, hence the 1st should do a faster reaction. Am I right, or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ce{CH3-CH-Br}$ will give faster $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction because when a nucleophile will approach $\ce{CH2=CH-Br}$ for $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction the double bond between $\ce{CH2=CH}$ will hinder its approach (steric effect), but there is no such hindrance in case of $\ce{CH3-CH2-Br}$.

To support the answer we can add one more point that in case of $\ce{CH3-CH2-Br}$ the charge $δ^+$ on the $\ce{C}$ atom of $\ce{CH2}$ will be greater in magnitude than that at the $\ce{C}$ atom of $\ce{CH}$ in case of $\ce{CH2=CH-Br}$ because the double bond has better −*I* effect than single bond, hence it will be easier for $\ce{-Br}$ to attract the shared electron pair towards it and develop a greater $δ^+$ charge on $\ce{C}$ in case of $\ce{CH3-CH2-Br}$, which will ultimately support the approach of the nucleophile for the $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction.

Answer (score 5):

There is no sense of comparing the reaction rate when one of the compound **doesn't** show S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism. And, that compound is $\ce{CH2=CHBr}$, due to the fact that it is a **vinyl halide**.

$\ce{CH2=CHBr}$ will **hinder the approach of nucleophile** due to the presence of **pi-electron cloud around double bond**.

And, therefore the obvious answer is $\ce{CH3-CH2Br}$

Comment: I think you mean that the obvious answer is ethyl bromide, rather than vinyl bromide, also considering your answer. Right?

Comment: @GürayHatipoğlu, +1 for pointing out!